# JavaScript function to change iframe video

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am trying to create a language translation page that allows different videos to be displayed when the associated button is clicked.

I need to create a group of buttons (with the country flag) for each language (currently 10) but I can't figure out how to change the video within a iframe depending on the language button selected.

The plan is to have the English language version initially visible but when a different language button is selected the video should change.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Change the video? Does that mean just change the source of the iframe?

Comment: Yes if I can change the source I think that would work.

Comment: You can change the source of an iframe using something like `document.getElementById("yourIframeId").src = "https://www.example.com/newFrameSource/`

Comment: `<a href="https://www.example.com/" target="myframe">foo</a><iframe name="myframe" id="myframe" />`

Comment: @epascarello Whoa, didn't know you could do that -- very cool!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's an example of how to change an iframe's src with buttons:

```js
videoFrame = document.getElementById('video');

function setLanguage(lang) {
  switch(lang) {
    case 'en':
      videoFrame.src = 'https://example.com/';
      break;
    case 'fr':
      videoFrame.src = 'https://french.com/';
      break;
  } 
}
```

```html
<button onclick="setLanguage('en')">English</button>
<button onclick="setLanguage('fr')">French</button>
<br><br>
<iframe id="video" src="https://example.com/"></iframe>
```

Comment: If you wanted to be even more fancy you could do `videoFrame.src = {"en": "https://example.com", "fr": "https://french.com"}[lang]`, although I guess you would need to handle out-of-bound indexes explicitly like that

Comment: Thanks everyone for you help.  I have got the video source to correctly change on my test page using Heath's code and just have to get it working properly with the Wordpress site.

Answer (score 1):

If you change the source of the video, you can get what you are looking for.

Try something like this:

```
video = document.getElementById("video");

var changeVideo = function(newVideo) {
    video.src = newVideo;
}
```

Then, you just have to call the function with the new video.